# Make qmake use qt5 by default

Tags: qt, qt4, qt5, qmake

I have both qt4 and qt5 on my Linux system. qt4 is used by default. What is a clean way to change that so that qmake uses qmake-qt5 by default?

Comment: Please provide output of `ls -l $(which qmake)`

Comment: `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 23 Sep  3 14:14 /usr/bin/qmake -> /usr/lib64/qt/bin/qmake*`

Comment: Isn't there something more elegant than messing with symlinks?

Comment: I dont know of any better and elegant way than that

Answer (score 17):

The system might have different meta packages that handle the default.
For example on Debian there is a `qt4-default` and a `qt5-default` package, installing one of them will uninstall the other and set the symlinks appropriately

Answer (score 14):

**Step 0**: Install qtchooser in your system.

```
$sudo apt-get install qtchooser
```

**Step 1**: locate your qtchooser configure file in your system.

```
$ locate qtchooser | grep conf

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt-default/qtchooser/default.conf
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qtchooser/4.conf
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qtchooser/5.conf
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qtchooser/qt4.conf
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qtchooser/qt5.conf
```

The command result may be different from yours. Those x.conf files represent all of qt versions qtchooser could recognized in your system. Each x.conf file is a symbolic link to a file configured the qt you have installed. Modifying the default.conf could configure the default qt version you expected.

**Step 2**: Find out the file location the symbolic link file default.conf linked to.

```
$ls -l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt-default/qtchooser/default.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 53 x xx xxx /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt-default/qtchooser/default.conf -> ../../../../share/qtchooser/qt4-x86_64-lnux-gnu.conf
```

**Step 3**: Create your qt version conf file

The result of step 2 shows the location of all qt version conf file: **/usr/share/qtchooser**. You just create a conf file specified your qt version in this path. For example, my qt is installed at **/opt/Qt5.13.1/** and I want to set this qt version as the default one in my system. We could create a file named like **qt5.13.1.conf**.

```
$cd /usr/share/qtchooser
$sudo vi qt5.13.1.conf
```

and fill in the following two lines: first line means the qmake location and another represents the library path.

```
/opt/Qt5.13.1/5.13.1/gcc_64/bin
/opt/Qt5.13.1/5.13.1/gcc_64/lib
```

**Step 4**: Set your qt as the default one.

Just modify the default.conf symbolic link to your qt conf file created at step 3.

```
$cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt-default/qtchooser/
$sudo ln -snf ../../../../share/qtchooser/qt5.13.1.conf default.conf
```

After complete those steps, the default qt has been configured and you can type following command to test and it should be your qt as the default.

```
$qmake -v
```

Comment: I did exactly what you said but i still get 5.12.8 from `qmake -v` instead of 6.6.1 which I installed in opt. Any idea?

Answer (score 11):

There is a tool named [qtchooser](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qtsdk/qtchooser.git/) to switch between Qt versions. On Debian and Ubuntu you can install it with `apt-get install qtchooser`.

Easiest way is to use it to list the alternatives and then create `QT_SELECT` environment variable.

```
$ qtchooser -list-versions
4
5
default
opt-qt55
qt4-i386-linux-gnu
qt4
qt5-i386-linux-gnu
qt5
```

Then you create `QT_SELECT` environment variable and set e.g. `export QT_SELECT=4` or `export QT_SELECT=5`.