# qmake -query returns an old Qt installation

Tags: qt, ubuntu, qmake

I would like to build Qt,
The command `qmake -query` returns an old Qt installation (5.7)

I searched at .config to look for some `qmake.conf` or `qt.conf`. I found the `trolltech.conf` file and `QtProject` folder. those two dont't contain any line returned by `qmake -query`.

I uninstalled qt4-qmake and qt5-qmake packages without success. The command is still returning the same output.

I tried to unset variables with `qmake -unset VARIABLE` but, it has effect only in variables i set with `qmake -set VARIABLE VALUE`.

I'm on `Linux/Ubuntu 16.04 LTS` and i would like to know how to do that qmake to do not point any Qt installation.
Thank you !

Comment: QMake default variables are built-in, do you call newly builded qmake or old one installed on your system?

Comment: Do you want to build Qt from sources or build your own app on specific Qt version? If you want to select a specific Qt version from multiple options you could use qtchooser, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39735998/make-qmake-use-qt5-by-default/39738181#39738181

Comment: @talamaki, i would like to build Qt from source and not an app.

Comment: @e.jahandar by default the old one is called, witch package to uninstall so that to do not have qmake anymore. Then i will restart from scratch

Comment: qmake normally embeds qt installation variables into itself, do you installed it via make install?

Comment: @e.jahandar no i installed from an installer

Comment: the command `dpkg -S /usr/bin/qmake` gave me qtchooser as output , normally i `sudo apt-get purge qtchoose` it should also remove `qmake` then i won't have anymore qmake. Is it right ?

Comment: qtchooser is wrapper to real qmake, you have to remove libqt5(4)-dev, but if you install qt by make && make install (also with --prefix=/usr) the installed qt will be overwritten

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's on you to invoke the correct `qmake`. It doesn't "just happen" by magic. Qt is meant to have multiple versions installed in parallel.

Alas, to build Qt itself you shouldn't be invoking qmake manually anyway. A Qt build, on all platforms, consists of two or three commands:

1. `configure ...`
2. `make -j#` / `gmake -j#` / `jom -j#` / `nmake`.
3. `make -j# install` / etc.